# Create a password file made up entirely of 18 of each character

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to create a script that generates a text file with every single character on the keyboard repeated 18 times.  Along the lines of:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

... and so on.  Is there a function I can feed ForEach-Object to make this happen?

Why do I want to do this?  I'm changing to a password policy that requires an 18 character minimum length, but complexity is not enforced.  I want to create a baseline blocklist that prevents someone from using those single character based passwords (if Microsoft allowed you to just configure a custom complexity policy that prevented x number of repeat character I'd just do that).  I figure there's something built into PowerShell that designates the entire ASCII character set (which would be sufficient for this exercise) but I'm not finding it.

Comment: Why not just enable complexity requirements? [AADs existing password scoring methodology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-password-ban-bad#score-calculation) would automatically score 18 repeated chars so low it wouldn't accept it

Comment: `'a'..'z' + 'A'..'Z' | % { "$_" * 18 }`

Comment: You can also use the ascii printable range: `[char[]](32..126) |% {[string]$_ * 18}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below snippet.

```
#Initializing the list variable
$list= @()

#intializing the variable $c with the byte of A
[byte]$c = [char]'A'

#iterating throug A - z (ABCD...Z...abcd...z) 
for ([byte]$c = [char]'A'; $c -le [char]'z'; $c++)  
{  
    $list += $(([char]$c).ToString() * 18)
}  

#Outputing the list to a file
$list |Out-File D:\list.txt
```

**Sample output :**

[image]

There will be some special characters between 'Z' and 'a', if you don't want them, you could have two iteration loops.

```
for ([byte]$c = [char]'A'; $c -le [char]'Z'; $c++) {.....}

for ([byte]$c = [char]'a'; $c -le [char]'z'; $c++) {.....}
```

Comment: Just to add, if i am not wrong - the password "aaaaaaa" will be considered weak and will not allow it to be set